# Magento 2: get current store view in JS

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, i18n

I need to get current store view code in JS component to compose i18n-compatible route to the REST API operation:

```
define(
    ["jquery", "ko", "uiComponent", "mage/translate"],
    function ($, ko, Component, translate) {
        "use strict"

        const URL_EMAIL = "/rest/V1/feedback/form/email"

        let url = "/" + storeCode + URL_EMAIL;
...
```

because `__('text to translate')` does not work in REST API code on server side w/o store view prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow below steps

1) in your block file

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

/**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }
```

2) in your phtml file

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "yourWidget": {
                    "storeCode": "<?php echo $block->getStoreCode(); ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

3) in your js file or define same into phtml file as you wish

```
define(['uiComponent'], function(Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this._super();
            console.log(this.storeCode);
        }
    });
});
```